# How to get the same tasks like inside the TaskListWebPart?

Tags: task-list

I am using sp2013. When you go to your mysite and go to the task list, you will see a webpart of the type TaskListWebPart. This webpart is showing all tasks from all site collections.

[image]

I have a custom webpart which is showing some content. I would like to show in this custom webpart also a list of all tasks. I would like to show only the Title of the task and make it an hyperlink to the task. Can someone tell me how to get the same data as the TaskListWebPart?

**NOTE**

The OOTB TaskListWebPart shows all tasks in all site collections and all webapplications where the "Work Management Service Application" is associated.

Comment: Try exporting that webpart and uploading it to wherever required

Comment: I would like to add it to my custom webpart. Only a list with the title of all tasks in all site collections.

Answer (score 0):

Do a Search for ContentType Task assignee:currentuser

that´s what that webpart does mainly. However, you won´t get tasks assigned to a group, the user belongs to. For doing this you at least have to change this to a SiteDataquery, querying for assignee:currentuser or user is member of (using the membership-element of CAML)

Comment: That webpart does more than that. Its a new feature in 2013 and there are dedicated services for rolling up those tasks on a timely basis.

Comment: Yes, but as long as you have all relevant sites in on search service application (along with its index) there won´t be any difference.

Difference will occur as soon as you have multiple search service applications, because a search request can only target on search service application and its index. Thats the point where you have to roll up all tasks over all possible locations in Sharepoint.

Comment: Can I do a search to get all tasks assigned to current user and get results from multiple webapplications?